# selenium get element class and text

Tags: selenium

I can't find test1,test2... from the folowing html page:

```
<dd class="class subclass">
test1, test2, test3
</dd>
```

tried 
//dd[contains(@class = 'class subclass') and contains(text(), 'test1')

I guess the problem in space? Or in dd tag?

PS getting error

ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]: //dd[contains(@class, "class subclass") and text() = test1]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//dd[contains(text(),"test1")]
```

Comment: "<dd class="class subclass"> test1, test2 </dd>" and i have
"Element //dd[contains(text(),'test1')] is not found!"

Comment: @sencor This should be the correct answer. Isn't your `<dd>` element hidden in an `<iframe>`? Isn't it created dynamically by javascript's innerHTML property?